# Code won't run, says there are issues, only says "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, arraylist

Tried to run the code, says exit status 1
Main.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    ArrayList result = ArrayList merge(one,two);
                               ^
  symbol:   variable ArrayList
  location: class Main

and similar errors...

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;

   class Main {
              public static void main(String[] args) {
              String[] one = {"in","one","now"};
              String[] two = {"here","in","two"};
              ArrayList<String> result = ArrayList<String> merge(one,two);
              System.out.println(result);
   }

              private static ArrayList<String> merge(String[] words, String[] more){
              ArrayList<String> sentence = new ArrayList<String>();
              for(String w:words) {ArrayList.add(w);}
              for(String w:more) {ArrayList.add(w);}
              return sentence;
   }
 }
```

Should return an ArrayList with contents of two string arrays combined, Thanks! :)

Comment: `ArrayList` doesn't have a static `add()` method. I think you meant `sentence.add(w)`.

Comment: Change ```ArrayList.add(w);``` to ```sentence.add(w);``` and change ```ArrayList<String> result = ArrayList<String> merge(one,two);``` to ``````ArrayList<String> result = merge(one,two);``````

Comment: `ArrayList<String> merge(one,two)` in the `main` function should be just `merge(one, two)`. I *strongly* suggest you find a good Java tutorial and work your way through it carefully. Not to be rude, but this is very basic Java -- and this level of Java is not one that's best learned from asking questions on Stack Overflow, as you'll quite soon find yourself locked out from asking questions due to downvotes.

Comment: Alternatively: `Collections.addAll(sentence, words);`

Answer (score 0):

First, `ArrayList` doesn't have a `static` method named `add`. You wanted to invoke that on `sentence`. And program to the `List` interface (you will need to import `java.util.List` as well); like

```
private static List<String> merge(String[] words, String[] more) {
    List<String> sentence = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String w : words) {
        sentence.add(w);
    }
    for (String w : more) {
        sentence.add(w);
    }
    return sentence;
}
```

Also, in `main` just call `merge` without adding more type information. Like,

```
List<String> result = merge(one, two);
```

The above `merge` could also be written with `Arrays.asList(T...)` and combine that with `Collections.addAll` like

```
private static List<String> merge(String[] words, String[] more) {
    List<String> sentence = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(words));
    sentence.addAll(Arrays.asList(more));
    return sentence;
}
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks everyone!! Just one of those days, distracted. Thanks again for all the help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] one = {"in","one","now"};
        String[] two = {"here","in","two"};
        ArrayList<String> result = merge(one,two);
        System.out.println(result);
       }

       private static ArrayList<String> merge(String[] words, String[] more){
        ArrayList<String> sentence = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String w:words) {sentence.add(w);}
        for(String w:more) {sentence.add(w);}
        return sentence;
       }
     }

     Console:[in,one,now,here,in,two]
```